# JavaScript Date.prototype.toISOString() not supported?

Tags: javascript

Both of these calls are returning errors in Chrome, latest version 53.0.2785.143, running on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
> new Date('2016-10-24 09:54:41').toISOString();
> "5441Not Supported8601"

> new Date().toISOString();
> "3639Not Supported8601"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: It works fine for me on Chrome 54.0.2840.71, Win 10.

Comment: This is definitely a bug. Please report it.

Comment: I've the following chrome version `54.0.2840.71` and works fine.

Comment: Also seeing this after updating Chrome to 54.0.2840.87 (64-bit), running on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: I've just updated to 54.0.2840.71 m on Windows and I'm not getting this issue. Specific to Mac? Definitely report it.

Comment: Issue reported to Google.